# Where is the list of formats for %c in strftime() defined?

Tags: linux, time, strftime

Where can I find the list of locale formats that the "%c" option of the `strftime()` function uses? I understand that the user may change the format to his own liking. But I am interested in the default such formats which I'm sure are defined somewhere in the Linux environment. Where is that?

Comment: `LC_TIME=de_DE locale LC_TIME` prints the LC_TIME strings for Allemagne.

Comment: `strftime()` man-page: `ENVIRONMENT
       The environment variables TZ and LC_TIME are used.
`

Comment: @stark Cool. Actually, using the `-ck` command line options of `locale`, it also tells you the name of locale parameter. For example: `date_fmt="%a %-d. %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"` for Deutschland.